# Undefined Reference to "typeinfo for <class>"

Tags: c++, linux

I saw questions about this problem but i can't find any solutions working for me. I am using Visual Code with C++ and C++ version is anterior to C++ 11.
I have DNS classes, with various classes inheriting a principal DNS message class, this way I can factorize some attributes. In function of the type type field I can know the type of the object.
When I compile I have an error "undefined reference to "typeinfo for DNS_RR_A" for example, but I got this at each dynamic cast I am doing to check the class of the object.

My dnsMessage.cpp only have constructor and destructor.

here is my classes:

```
class CDnsMessage
{       
    public:
        CDnsMessage();
        virtual ~CDnsMessage();

        virtual void GetSize() = 0;

        uint32_t       m_ttl;
        eDnsClass      m_class;
        eDnsType       m_type; 
        std::string    m_domain; 
        uint8_t        m_sizeDnsCorpse;
        uint8_t        m_sizeDomainName; 
};

class CDns_RR_A : public CDnsMessage
{
    public:
        CDns_RR_A();
        virtual ~CDns_RR_A();

        virtual void GetSize() {/*....*/}

        uint32_t        m_address;
};
```

And here is a sample of my function using with the error at the dynamic cast. I receive a message I have to encode but I don't know the nature of the message so I dynamic cast so I can adapt my encode:

```
//i receive a message i have to encode, i don't know the type 
void EncodeOpaqueData(CDnsMessage & msg, std::vector<uint8_t>& output)
{
//where i encode
    output.clear();

    // Error : "undefined reference to `typeinfo for CDns_RR_A'"
    if(dynamic_cast< CDns_RR_A* >( &msg ) != NULL) 
    {       
            CDns_RR_A* RR_A_msg = dynamic_cast< CDns_RR_A* >( &msg );

            uint16_t dnstype = cmn_hton16(1);
            output.push_back(dnstype);
            output.push_back(dnstype >> 8);
            /* stuff here */

            uint32_t address = cmn_hton32(RR_A_msg->m_address);
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                    output.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(address >>(i * 8)));
            }

    }
}
```

After think more of the function, instead of checking the type of the object I could check msg->m_type and adapt in function of the type, the m_type variable can be wrongly instantiated for example. But anyway I would like to understand this error and how to fix it.
thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all please try to create a [mcve] to show us, one that replicates the problem and that we ourselves could try. Then show (by copy-paste as text) the full and complete error (or even build) output from building the example. And lastly please add comments in the code you show, to tell us where the errors are.

Comment: Are you building RTTI (Run-Time Type Information) disabled (e.g. the `-fno-rtti` GCC option)? RTTI is needed for `dynamic_cast` to work.

Comment: How can i know it? i'm using a Jenkins job to compile it, as every one do in my team team (i'm in internship so i'm a beginner)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class impedimenta—virtual method table and typeinfo—are generated when the first declared virtual method is compiled. Are you *defining* the `virtual ~CDnsMessage();` (i.e. `CDnsMessage::~CDnsMessage() {}`) and is the file where it is defined included in the link.

Note that out-of-line definitions are not weak, so it must be defined in exactly one source (not header) file.

Comment: Yes, in my CDnsMessage.cpp i have CdnsMessage::~CDnsMessage{} (empty because i have nothing to do in it at the moment)

Comment: My differents classes are in the same .h, can i put the constructor and destructor of each subclasses in the same .cpp of the main class CdnsMessage ? How do i have to separate them?

Comment: @RaphaelLopes, the separation to compilation units (`.cpp` files) is completely orthogonal to separation to classes, so put them wherever you think you'll be looking for them next year. The usual convention is to have headers and sources correspond to each other, and have separate ones for each class, named the same as the class, but for small classes you can slap them together.

Comment: Added the define for each destructor as you said and it works now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the reference parameter to a pointer like this:

```
void EncodeOpaqueData(CDnsMessage * msg, std::vector<uint8_t>& output)
```

You have the explanation here:

[Difference in behavior while using dynamic_cast with reference and pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276847/difference-in-behavior-while-using-dynamic-cast-with-reference-and-pointers)

Comment: There is a difference in behaviour, but either way it requires the class impedimenta.

Comment: the difference is that when it fails then in one case you get a null poiner in the other an exception, but that does not explain why it fails, nor how to fix it. Anyhow, the answer should be self-contained and at least summarize the linked answer. If the link alone would be enough (it isnt) the question should rather be flagged as duplicate